# Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: <function> is not defined

Tags: reactjs

I'm really new to ReactJs and currently struggling to create an onClick event, that will take the href value of itself and pass it to a function called 'action'.

The action function should then prevent the default browser behavior, perform a GET request to the passed in URL, and show an alert dialog containing the response and status.

However I am stuck trying to call my function from the onClick event with the following error:

> Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: action is not defined

```
var Content = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            teams: []
        }
    },

    componentDidMount: function() {
        const makeRequest = () => axios.get("http://localhost:5000/api/teams").then(({ data }) => this.setState({ teams: data }));

        this.serverRequest = makeRequest();

        this.poll = setInterval(() => {
            this.serverRequest = makeRequest();
        }, 10000)
    },

    componentWillUnmount: function() {
        this.serverRequest.abort();

        clearInterval(this.poll)
    },

    action: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $.get(e.href, function(res, status) {
            alert("Response: " + res + "\nStatus: " + status);
        });
    },

    render: function() {
        const { teams } = this.state;

        return (
            <div className="list-group">
                { teams.map(function(team) {
                    return ([
                        <a href={ "http://localhost:5000/api/teams?name=" + team.name} onClick={ action }>Click Me</a>
                    ]);
                })}
            </div>
        )
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(<Content />, document.getElementById('content'));
```

Comment: What is unclear about the error? The variable `action` doesn't exist inside `render`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `this.action` instead of `action`.

**UPDATE**

I found the problem. It is all about scope. You can't access `this` inside `map`.

```
render: function() {
    const { teams } = this.state;

    return (
        <div className="list-group">
            { teams.map((team) => {
                return ([
                    <a href={ "http://localhost:5000/api/teams?name=" + team.name} onClick={ this.action }>Click Me</a>
                ]);
            })}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried that and resulted in: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'action' of undefined

Comment: Better use an arrow function than `that`.

Comment: Thanks! That did it

Answer (score 1):

Its a binding issue, try this it will work:

```
render: function() {
    const { teams } = this.state;

    return (
        <div className="list-group">
            { teams.map((team,i)=>{
                    return <a key={i} href={ "http://localhost:5000/api/teams?name=" + team.name} onClick={ this.action }>Click Me</a>
                })
            }
        </div>
    )
}
```

**Suggestion**: Whenever creating html elements dynamically, always assign the unique key to each element, `key` value will keep your components uniquely identified.

From [Facebook React Doc](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lists-and-keys.html):

> Keys help React identify which items have changed, are added, or are removed. Keys should be given to the elements inside the array to give the elements a stable identity.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I forgot to require the function.
So my suggestion is, please do check the function is imported correctly.

Comment: It better suits a comment